# How does rosjava relate to ROS?

Tags: ros, clearpath, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have several years experience with Java, but I am brand new to ROS.  For my academic program, I will be working with Clearpath robotics products such as the Husky and Kingfisher.  This week, I discovered rosjava.

I am wondering how rosjava turns into instructions for a robot running ROS.  Does the robot have a JVM that executes the Java bytecode?  Does rosjava compile the Java into ROS-executable code?  Or does rosjava create nodes external to the robot that can communicate to the ROS system?

Thank you for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40871/how-does-rosjava-relate-to-ros?/) by [David Kaczynski](https://answers.ros.org/users/2982/david-kaczynski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosjava provides Java classes for creating ROS Nodes in java and communicating with any ROS node, as well as a java implementation of a ROS master.

To run java or rosjava on a robot, you only need a standard JVM on the robot.
You can run rosjava nodes anywhere, on the robot or remotely, and they do not need the java rosmaster to run.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0